# Controlling a flat brushless DC motor with integrated speed controller

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, speed

I have recently purchased the [Brushless DC-Flat Motors Series 2610](https://www.faulhaber.com/en/products/series/2610b-sc/) from Faulhaber and I am honestly new to this type of motor as it’s pins are not like any other I have used before. I would appreciate any help on how to connect and code this motor to rotate on an arduino using the integrated speed controller in the motor.

Comment: Everything you need to know is in the datasheet. The built in speed controller uses the industry standard 0-10V input signal to control the speed.

Comment: What exactly is your problem with it? Have you read the datasheet? Is there something, that you don't understand?

Comment: I read the data sheet, but I’m not very good with motors and arduinos so didn’t really know where each pin should be connected to and how to command it to rotate in varying speeds. I apologize for the lack of knowledge and if my question is stupid

Comment: You need a circuit to generate 0-10V analogue voltage. You can probably find a shield to do it.